# Prime Mean of Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

1) Are there infinitely many primes $p_1,p_2$ such that $\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}$ is also prime?

2) What can we say about the more general problem :

Are there infinitely many primes $p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_n$ such that $\frac{p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n}{n}$ is also a prime for $n\geq 1$?

$\mathbf{Remark}$: Note that for $n=1$, the problem 2 is solved by Euclid's theorem.

Comment: For the first question, you are asking whether there are infinitely many 3-term arithmetic progressions of primes. I think it has been proved that this is true. @Bellington, did you notice that after adding, we're dividing by 2?

Comment: No, just take the largest and smallest of the pair of three and take the average. You'll get the third.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both cases follow from the fact that there exist progressions in primes of length $k,$ for each $k\ge 2.$ This is [Green-Tao Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem).

**Remark:** case $n=2$ was proved by K.Roth.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know of the theorem. Thanks @leshik.